# ManyToMany association query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a question based on the Doctrine 2.X ManyToMany association. My data structure:

```
news:
    id: INT

program_site:
    id: INT

news_program_site:
    newsId: INT
    programSiteId: INT
```

Extract out of my News.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ProgramSite")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="news_program_site",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="newsId", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="programSiteId", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *  )
 */
private $programSites;
```

My question:
Is it possible to get all news which have an entity in `news_program_site` for the identifier X.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM news AS n INNER JOIN news_program_site AS s ON s.newsId = n.id WHERE s.programSiteId IN(2, 3)
```

Thanks for your help!

Greets,
Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing SQL.  Doctrine is different. You don't interact with the many-to-many table directly.  Doctrine handles that.  I think the query you want is:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT n FROM news n JOIN program_site ps");
$users = $query->getResult();
```

Then you would process news as entities, and call news.getProgramSite() for a list of ProgramSites associated with an a news entity.  You may add a where clause to the query (for example to get news items joined to specific programsite), but based on your description, I don't think you need it.

This is a fundamentally different paradigm than SQL and will take some getting used to.